# Tracking Image Impressions In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, rss

I am currently trying to track Image displays on Images set in a Custom field of a Custom Post Type I have setup. There are a lot of plugins that claim to track a lot of stuff in WordPress, but the issue I am having is I need to track these images when being displayed on the pages directly, widgets onsite, carousels onsite, as well as when being served via RSS.

I have considered using query strings, but the issue I have with this is the query string could easily be stripped out by someone calling our RSS feeds.

Given this, I am looking to change the URL structure of these images and have them served similar to how other plugins do this. Basically, www.something.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg would be www.something.com/image/image.jpg. This would basically force the serving of the image to occur from WordPress, rather than going direct to the server location.

Once this portion is completed I would need to somehow track how many times these URLS are being accessed and be able to access this data so I can create a backend dashboard to view the amount of image views per post.

I know that I could always use the server access logs and try and pull and store this data into WordPress, but this seems like using a sledge hammer when all I need is a rubber mallet.

Any assistance or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can accomplish this with Google tag manager.  In combination with Universal analytics, and triggers that are defined as you describe (particular pages, etc.) you could easily handle this. Plus easily create a custom dashboard with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am investigating this now.